# Como atribuir uma Activity para abrir ao clicar na ActionBar Tab?

Tags: android, android-fragment, actionbar, android-adapter

## Contexto

Possuo uma aplicação que contém uma `Activity` chamada `MapActivity` (da qual é uma atividade do tipo Mapa que herda do GoogleMaps api), e outra `Activity` comum que servirá como uma busca com filtros para refinar os resultados que irão aparecer na `Activity` do mapa.

> Minha aplicação tem a versão api mínima(*minSdkVersion*) como: *15* e possui como versão api alvo(*SdkTarget*) como: *22*(atual)

## Código

```java
public class MapaFiltrosActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mapa_filtros);

        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {

            switch (i){
                case 0: actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                                        .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                                        .setTabListener(this)
                                        ); break;

                case 1: actionBar.addTab(
                        actionBar.newTab()
                                .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                                .setTabListener(new TabListener<MapFragment>(R.layout.activity_map, this, "Mapa", MapActivity.class))
                                ); break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

No código acima, só coloquei a parte que está dentro do `onCreate()` que acredito ser onde posso manipular essa chamada de atividades.

## Código do PageAdapter

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        //total pages
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

## Dúvida

A questão em si é que eu não consigo atribuir um `TabListener` para o `Tab` da `ActionBar`, da forma que estou fazendo que é a seguinte:

```java
actionBar.addTab(
    actionBar.newTab()
    .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
    .setTabListener(
        new TabListener<MapFragment>(R.layout.activity_map, this, "Mapa", MapActivity.class))
);
```

O problema está no `new TabListener()` que o compilador não consegue identificar e tampouco sugerir para alterar por outro ou para importar algum tipo de biblioteca.

Detalhe é que não sei se esta maneira está correta, e se não estiver, gostaria de saber: **por qual maneira eu poderia atribuir uma atividade corretamente para o `Tab` da minha `ActionBar`?**

Comment: Confira se todos os *imports* relacionados com ActionBar e Fragment se referem à android.support.v7.app. Por exemplo `import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab;` e não `import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;`

Comment: Sim, o `ActionBar` e o `ActionBarActivity` estão vindo da `android.support.v7.app` mas o `ActionBar.Tab` nem está importado na minha aplicação

Answer (score 2):

Esta parte do código não está correta:

```
actionBar.addTab(
    actionBar.newTab()
    .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
    .setTabListener(
        new TabListener<MapFragment>(R.layout.activity_map), this, "Mapa", MapActivity.class)
);
```

O método `setTabListener()` aceita apenas um argumento e você está a passar 4.

Retire o `)` a seguir a `R.layout.activity_map` e coloque-o antes do `;`

```
actionBar.addTab(
    actionBar.newTab()
    .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
    .setTabListener(
        new TabListener<MapFragment>(R.layout.activity_map, this, "Mapa", MapActivity.class)
));
```

O argumento a passar ao `setTabListener()` tem de ser uma classe que implemente a *interface TabListener*

Você terá de escrever essa classe. Não lhe chame `TabListener` para que não se confunda com a interface.

Por outro lado a sua *activity* já implementa essa interface, passe `this` como fez no `case 0:`. Confesso que não percebi completamente o que pretender fazer.

**Nota:** Com o surgimento do Android 5 as *ActionBar tabs* passaram a ser consideradas *deprecated*. Neste momento a forma de implementar tabs é utilizando *TabLayout*, veja [aqui](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout) como.

Comment: como eu deveria implementar esta classe? não imagino como fazer

Comment: Confesso que não percebi completamente o que quer fazer.

Comment: só quero que ao clicar nas minhas tabs ele mude de atividade, apenas isso.

Comment: Obrigado por alertar que o fechamento dos parênteses estava incorreto, porém da mesma forma não foi possível, continuo com o mesmo problema. Porém editei na minha pergunta.

Comment: Você já implementa a interface*TabListener* na sua *Activity*, portanto deve, no `setTabListener()` do `case 1:`, passar `this` também. Na implementação da interface deve usar o seu *PagerAdapter* para alternar entre *fragments*

Comment: desculpe, não consegui entender. Poderia complementar sua resposta com uma solução?

Comment: A implementação de qualquer solução depende do que você quer fazer. Colocar como resposta a forma de utilizar *Fragments*, *PagerAdapter* *Tablistener*, etc é quase como que escrever um livro sobre o assunto:).

Comment: Mas eu realmente não sei o que fazer eu só sei que não está funcionando. Esse é o problema. Eu só quero que funcione.

Comment: Poste o código do *PageAdapter*

Comment: postado, editei a pergunta

Comment: Esse código é seu ou foi buscá-lo [aqui](https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/android-studio-and-placeholderfragment)? Isso que postou não vem ajudar nada. Poste o código da classe *PlaceholderFragment*

Comment: Acabei de editar a pergunta com ele, O código foi gerado pelo proprio AndroidStudio, quando eu cliquei New -> Activity -> Tabbed Activity -> Navigation style: Action Bar Tabs